# Where can I watch all 43 episodes of Princess Comet?

Tags: princess-comet

I feel an urge to watch [*Princess Comet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Princess_Comet) (aka *Cosmic Baton Girl Princess Comet*) again which I watched once when I was a child. But the thing is that I know this anime has 43 episodes and in all anime providing websites I have looked at can only find 22 episodes.

Where can I find all 43 episodes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Amazon has the Japanese DVDs still listed for sale.  For official releases, that's probably your best bet; to my knowledge no **official** source for English of this anime would exist, since it hasn't been licensed for physical distribution in America or any other English-speaking country (as far as I can tell).

Comment: the wikipedia page does say *"It was also later aired by Animax, which translated and dubbed the series into English"* however this doesn't mean it was broadcast or licensed in the US as *Moero Chronicle*, up until recently was available in english but not in the US but in China and wikipedia doesn't say where Animax aired it in

Comment: @Memor-X:  I should probably clarify that I didn't see it licensed for home video release, since broadcast licenses are different than distribution licenses.